# Can there be more abstract unit test cases in Jest?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I recently started learning unit testing with Jest. I started with the classic FizzBuzz problem. The tutorials I'm seeing, all of them test for specific inputs.

i.e. :

```
it('returns Fizz for multiples of 3', () => {
expect(fizzbuzz(6)).toBe('Fizz');
expect(fizzbuzz(9)).toBe('Fizz');
})
```

And after these 2-3 `expect` statements, they declare the 'test case handled'.

Question is: Could we write something like this below, for a more abstract approach?

```
it('returns Fizz for multiples of 3', (num) => {
if (num % 3 === 0){
expect(fizzbuzz(num)).toBe('Fizz');
}
})
```

I tried it and it gives me some errors. It's either myself or this is not a good approach.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's *not* a good approach to have conditional expectations. By all means group test cases with the same expectations into a *parameterised test* (e.g. `[3, 6, 9, 12, 18, 21].forEach((num) => { it(\`returns Fizz for ${num}\`, () => { expect(fizzbuzz(num)).toBe('Fizz'); }); });`), but I wouldn't recommend your current approach.

Comment: You could write that kind of test (nevermind how for the moment), but then you're more or less repeating the implementation of `fizzbuzz` itself inside your test. You're now depending on `num % 3 === 0` being implemented bug-free. As long as that's only a single line of code, that's probably fine most of the time, but if it gets any more complicated, you'd now need a test for your tests. That's why you should write test "as dumb as possible".

Comment: Not leaving a place for human mistakes is the reason why tests are so specific. In case tests can be generated from a set of expectations, Jest has `test.each` that can be used instead of `forEach`.

Comment: Thank you everyone! That clarified it for me.